# parse and get specific field from HTTP response in java

Tags: java, gson, json

I try to parse a HTTP response to a `JSONObject` and retrieve some fields, coould be a String or int.
My response is a json array like this:

```
[{nid: "24161",changed: 1445936169,created: "1444728767",language: "en",status: 1,title: "bicycle",type: "product",uid: "2172",vid: "24161"}]
```

And I tried using:

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

And `gson` , still after parsing the response turns to `{}`.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing json array into object. Use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`

```
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

you can get your object by index from your array.

Comment: Works like charm, but how to get a field by key?

Comment: once you got the object form your array, you can call `myObjectAtIndexZero.get("nid")`

Comment: will it work for other indexes as well, marking your answer as right when I can.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
```

You can then iterate throw the array and get the fields you want

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String nid = object.getString("nid");
    int changed = object.getInt("changed");
    //...
}
```